# Pick image from gallery on api 17 can return a somewhat empty image

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview

Noticed while testing on an older device a galaxy s4 api 17 that when choosing an image from the gallery.  Done like this.

```
} else { // pick from file
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), Constants.PICK_FROM_FILE);
}
```

the image would essentially be empty/hidden, except that in another functionality in my app I could still do a crop on this hidden/empty image and return a correct crop of the hidden section except this was now visible.

To test I set it to the image view I was putting in the cropped image and instead but in the result of the bitmap I received but it was also empty still it was done like this.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.PICK_FROM_FILE ) {
            if (data != null) {
                try {
                    isFromCamera = false;

                    Constants.INSTANCE.IMAGE_PATH = data.getData();

                    Bitmap bitmap =  MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Constants.INSTANCE.IMAGE_PATH);

                    Constants.INSTANCE.IMAGE = bitmap;
                    imageViewUser.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    Constants.INSTANCE.mFromPhotoSelection = true;
                    performCrop(Uri.parse(""));
```

Now this seems to work on most images on the s4, and every image on the lollipop devices I have been testing on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bitmap bitmap =  MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Constants.INSTANCE.IMAGE_PATH);
```

This only works if you get an image from the `MediaStore`. There is no requirement that the user choose an activity to handle your `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` request that will return an image from the `MediaStore`. Worse, you are doing this IPC and disk I/O on the main application thread, freezing your UI in the meantime.

There are many [image loading libraries available for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), such as Picasso. Most will take a `Uri` and load your image asynchronously. I strongly encourage you to use one.

Otherwise, use `openInputStream()` on your `ContentResolver`, along with `BitmapFactory`, on a background thread, to get your `Bitmap`.